# How can i make this border to the end?CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this short example:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/6ae7vumn/)

**CODE HTML:**

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="menu-collapse">MENU</div>
</div>
```

**CODE CSS:**

```
.header{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid grey;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
}

    .menu-collapse {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-right: 2px solid red;
        padding: 0px 10px 0 10px;
        height: 100%;
}
```

My problem is that border (red border) is not until the end header.

There is a space both top and bottom in.
CSS code in the header must remain exactly the same

Can you help me to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: set padding 0px for .header and add line-height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set padding 0px for header and add line-height

```
.header{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid grey;
    padding: 0;
    line-height:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

remove padding from the .header class. This space is header's padding.  And add the padding to the .menu-collapse class.

```
.header{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid grey;    
}

    .menu-collapse {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-right: 2px solid red;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        height: 100%;
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ThetHlaing10/8uzxb9o8/).

Answer (score 0):

Remove Padding from `header` and provide `top & bottom padding` too to `menu-collapse`.
Try this:

```css
.header{
        width:300px;
        height:auto;
        border:1px solid grey;
    }
    .menu-collapse {
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-right: 2px solid red;
        padding: 5px;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<div class="header">
    <div class="menu-collapse">MENU</div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
https://jsfiddle.net/6ae7vumn/3/

```
.header{
    width:300px;
    height:auto;
    border:1px solid grey;
}

.menu-collapse {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-right: 2px solid red;
    padding: 15px 5px;
    height: 100%;}
```

You dont need to use padding in header